# Problems on Installing NuGet

Tags: powershell, nuget

however i try to install NuGet for Windows Powershell i run into errors.
I want to install "Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force", but i always get the Error:

```
    WARNUNG: Es kann kein Download von URI "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409" nach ""
durchgeführt werden.
WARNUNG: Die Liste der verfügbaren Anbieter kann nicht heruntergeladen werden. Überprüfen Sie Ihre Internetverbindung.
PackageManagement\Install-PackageProvider : Für die angegebenen Suchkriterien für Anbieter "NuGet" wurde keine
Übereinstimmung gefunden. Der Paketanbieter erfordert das PackageManagement- und Provider-Tag. Überprüfen Sie, ob das
angegebene Paket über die Tags verfügt.
In C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:7468 Zeichen:21
+ ...     $null = PackageManagement\Install-PackageProvider -Name $script:N ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Power...PackageProvider:InstallPackageProvider) [Install-Pac
   kageProvider], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForProvider,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackagePro
   vider

PackageManagement\Import-PackageProvider : Für die angegebenen Suchkriterien und den Anbieternamen "NuGet" wurde keine
Übereinstimmung gefunden. Führen Sie "Get-PackageProvider -ListAvailable" aus, um festzustellen, ob der Anbieter im
System vorhanden ist.
In C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:7474 Zeichen:21
+ ...     $null = PackageManagement\Import-PackageProvider -Name $script:Nu ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (NuGet:String) [Import-PackageProvider], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.ImportPackageProv
   ider
```

I already tried to user this:
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

Didn't work. I dont know what could be wrong.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, TLS 1.2 will be required.  Curious: Are you running it from an elevated (Administrator) Windows PowerShell session?  What does `Get-ExecutionPolicy` indicate?  Are you using a proxy server, or client-side software-based firewall?  If so, is your user account permissioned to access Internet content through your proxy, and is the proxy port open on your firewall?  Perhaps `Install-Module –Name PowerShellGet –Force –Verbose` might help beforehand.  Worth checking.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I read somewhere that the certs for the nuget repo were expired recently... but I can't find where I might have seen it, so it could totally have been ages ago. I don't suppose it would just... work now?